# How to get Alfresco webscript JSON response in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, ajax, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm working on alfresco maven sdk project.

So i have a repo webscript who return a json response template containinng the list of files contained in a specific folder (in my case it's: `Espace%20racine/Dictionnaire%20de%20données/Dossier%20Workflow`).

The template response.json.ftl is here:

```
{ 
  "Files" : [
    <#list folder.children as child>
    <#if child.isDocument>
    {
        "name" : "${child.name}"
    }
    <#if child_has_next>,</#if>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  ]
}
```

My webscript works fine, and when i run it through the commande line or the browser, i get a response like:

```
    { 
"Files" : [
        {
        "name" : "test"
    }
    ,
    {
        "name" : "test2"
    }
    ,
    {
        "name" : "test3"
    }

  ]
}
```

Now, i want to invoke my webscript from a javascript file who reside in the folder web of share, but i haven't idea to how achieve this. I searched on the net but i don't find a consistant example to how manage this.

It'll help me lot if anyone can tell me the way to achieve this or take me an example to how achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for making an ajax call in alfresco share.There are other methods also available like Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPost,Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPut etc..In below console.log(response.json) will print the response in console.

```
 var fnSuccess = function RESPONSE_functionName(response)
     {
        console.log(response.json)//Here you will get response json.
     };
     var fnFailure = function RESPONSE_functionName(response)
     {
        Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage({text:"Failure"});
     };
    Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet(
     {
        url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "REPOSITORY_WEBSCRIPT_URL",
        successCallback:
        {
           fn: fnSuccess,
           scope: this
        },
        failureCallback:
        {
           fn: fnFailure,
           scope: this
        }
     });
```